# evil-mode exec register ignores pipe

Tags: evil, registers

In vim, assume `:r!ls | grep foo` is in the register **l**.

You can then do: `@l` to exec `ls | grep foo` and insert the contents matching foo in to the current buffer.

In evil-mode I get:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Is this a bug, or a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the many unimplemented Ex features in Evil. There's nothing you're overlooking, except maybe a chance to contribute it.